# Add CGImage to CGImageDestination at specific index

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, cgimage

Is there an option to add `CGImage` to specific index inside `CGImageDestination`?

We tried using `CGImageDestinationAddImage` but it adds images at a incremental order. We are creating some expensive `CGImages` where we need to add them in multiple indexes inside the destination. We thought about adding them to all needed "indexes" at once, saving the recreation.

```
generator.generateCGImagesAsynchronously(forTimes: <BigArrayOfTimes>, completionHandler: { (requestedTime, expensiveCgImage, actualTime, result, error) in
   CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, expensiveCgImage, frameProperties as CFDictionary)
   // How can I add the CGImage in more known indexes, before releasing the CGImage?
})
```

Comment: Show your work.

Comment: Hey @ElTomato . There isn't really what to show. the "CGImageDestinationAddImage" is pretty clear. I've updated the question to elaborate a little more.

Comment: "There isn't really what to show."  Where does 'expensiveCgImage' come from, then?  One cannot tell whether it comes from an array of images or what.

Comment: @ElTomato I've added sample code. The images coming from 'generateCGImagesAsynchronously' used with Video Composition.